# Which is better way to store boolean in cassandra, text column vs boolean column?

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling

Want to know the better way to store `boolean` in Cassandra between these two approaches:

1. Store it as a `text` column with a single character. e.g: 'Y' or 'N'.
2. Use the `boolean` column. e.g: true or false

Comment: I wish more people would ask this question.  Then we might have fewer instances of UUIDs stored as `string`s.

Answer (score 3):

Cassandra stores all data as hex byte arrays, so Erick is right in that it's really ok to use either.

I will say that I would *strongly* recommend using the `boolean` type, for two reasons:

- Overall size.  `boolean` takes 1 bit, versus a `string` of "true" which takes 4 bytes.  That difference might not be too concerning today, but it's worth pointing out.
- Data quality.  Using a `string` leaves your app open to having to interpret different values like "true", "True", "Y", "y", "yes"...etc.  Which all mean the same thing.  Using a `boolean` removes any chance of ambiguity or invalid data.

Comment: Thank you so much for the details and we do have huge data in the table that we are planning to add to this column and boolean seems ideal option here.

Answer (score 2):

It's OK to use either.

Using the CQL `boolean` type means that you can easily map it to the boolean type in whatever language your app is written in.

On the other hand, if your source is not boolean then it's easier to store it in CQL `text` type so you don't need to implement the logic that would convert `Y` to `true` and `N` to `false` in your app.

It really comes down to preference. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation. This makes sense.